# How to remove google map Direction paths?

Tags: google-maps

I need to remove the Direction paths drawn on Google map? I know how to remove markers, but when you remove markers path is not getting cleared. Is there a way to remove the direction path than creating map from the beginning again?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the same way as removing the markers (Google is using the setMap as a standard now).
A good practice is always define a global array variables for your markers, polylines and directions..etc:

```
var markers = [];
var drArr = [];
var pArr = [];

...
// whenever you set a marker, add it to the markers array
markers.push(marker);

...
// whenever you create a DirectionsRenderer instance, add it to the DirectionsRenderer array
drArr.push(directionsRenderer);

...
// whenever you create a Polyline instance, add it to the Polyline array
pArr.push(polypath);


// This is used to reset the map
function resetMap() {
    // remove Markers
    for(i=0; i < markers.length; i++)
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    // remove DirectionsRenderers
    for(i=0; i < drArr.length; i++)
        drArr[i].setMap(null);
    // remove Polylines
    for(i=0; i < pArr.length; i++)
        pArr[i].setMap(null);
}
```

as you can see, you can seperate the resetMap function to functions (like resetMarkers..etc).

Hope this help.